# crontab in MacOSX

Tags: macos, emacs, cron

I'm trying to set up a bi-directional sync between org and google calendar, following instruction from http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-google-sync.html. One headache is that seems MAC OSX Mountain lion has deprecated the cron of Unix. So the question is how to achieve the crontab in the figure... Thanks!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a task to run every so often?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132955/how-do-i-set-a-task-to-run-every-so-often)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the unix crontab has indeed been depricated.  It has been replaced by "launchd".

The [Apple developer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) states that

> Although it is still supported, cron is not a recommended solution. It
>   has been deprecated in favor of launchd.

Cron will still work when you are logged in, but it would be better to use launchd.  Look [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist) for more info on how to write a launchd job.

Good Luck!