# Moving files to different location based on color tag using AppleScript

Tags: tags, applescript, metadata

I'm a bit new to AppleScript.  I would like to start moving files that are tagged "green" in finder to a different location.  This would be to start with.

Ideally, I'm using the program "Capture One" and within that program you can tag images green which is stored as metadata.  I would like to write an AppleScript to scan the image folder for any images with the metadata tag "green" and move those images to another location on a server.  I would like to have the script scan the folder every hour.

I have searched around quite a bit and have found difficulty in getting a clear idea on how to approach this process.

Thank you kindly for your time and help!

Comment: Are you limited to applescript, or can you use bash? With a shell script you can do this: `mdls -name kMDItemUserTags "$file" | grep Green && mv "$file" "$new_location"`

Comment: cool thanks, i will try that.  i'm not limited to applescript, i just thought that would be the best when attempting to communicate with the Capture One program.

Comment: OK, since it is a suitable approach, I created an answer that will be more useful for others who see this. I don't think you need to *communicate* with Capture One: that program helps you tag files, and you can have a completely separate program (script) to check for tagged files and do whatever you want with the files.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: this is the "no-applescript" answer. I asked in comments
>   if applescript was a requirement, answer was no, so I explored
>   non-applescript solutions. I imagine a proper applescript-based
>   solution is still welcome.

You can create a shell script to do that:

```
#!/bin/sh
SOURCE_FOLDER="/path/to/source/folder"
TARGET_FOLDER="/path/to/target/folder"
find "$SOURCE_FOLDER" -type f | while read file
do
    mdls -name kMDItemUserTags "$file" | grep Green && mv "$file" "$TARGET_FOLDER"
done
```

See [How do I set a task to run every so often?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132955/6730571) to schedule this every hour.

Edit: I have long forgotten how to write Applescript, but for a double-clickable application with no code, you can try with "Automator":

- New -> Application
- from Library, select "Files & Folders"
- pick "Find Finder Items" and drag it to your workflow
- pick "Move Finder Items" and drag it to your workflow

[image: Automator setup]

(although this will work for files that have the Green tag and no other tag, but you can specify more complex rules)

Comment: amazing, thank you for the help!  just out of curiosity, is it not possible to target color tagged files in finder via applescript?