# Recurring function at date/time

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to call a function when my macOS application is in any state, including terminated. Here is what i'm trying to accomplish:

Schedule a function (much like `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()`) to run daily at a given time (let's say 9AM). I would like to add a feature to my application that allows a user to pick a time of day, and have an Alamofire POST request run at that time every day.

I have tried using a `Runloop`, and more recently Grand Central Dispatch:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + .seconds(60)) {
        //Alamofire
    }
```

I can easily accomplish this while the application is running with a timer, but have yet to find a way to accomplish this in the background, with the app running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be pretty heavy to implement (i.e. not straightforward), but if you want a task to run even if your app is terminated, you might need to consider [writing your own LaunchAgent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132955/how-do-i-set-a-task-to-run-every-so-often).

The trick here would be for the agent to be able to interact with your application (retrieving or sending shared information).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was hoping to avoid making a launch agent, for the reason you mentioned, however i'll try doing that and see where I end up. Thanks.