# How to schedule Anaconda Jupyter note book on Macbook pro?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am working on Mac OS(MacBook Pro) and can't find a way to run my anaconda Jupyter notebook script there automatically every day without the laptop on?

Comment: Does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132955/how-do-i-set-a-task-to-run-every-so-often

Comment: Sorry to not mention this earlier but I want to know that can we automate it without the laptop on? @MichaelDelgado

Comment: For something to run a computer has to be turned on. If you need to run the code regardless of the status of the laptop, deploy the code to a server (a small VPS/droplet is easily available for $5/month, or you could get yourself a raspberry pi which is very popular for these kinds of things)

Comment: @beenuntz can you clarify what you're hoping to do? Are you trying to get your laptop to boot itself on a regular schedule and run a command? Or are you looking for help setting up a automated workflow on the cloud? Either way, this is not an issue with jupyter but a general scheduled job running question.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs.
I have dedicated one desktop to run the code automatically every day.